# Auto filling polymorphic table on save or on delete in django

Tags: python, django

Am working on an project in which I made an app "core" it will contain some of the reused models across my projects, most of those are polymorphic models (Generic content types) and will be linked to different models.

Example below am trying to create audit model and will be linked to several models which may require auditing.

This is the polls/models.py

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from core.models import *
from django.contrib.contenttypes import generic

class Poll(models.Model):
    ## TODO: Document
    question = models.CharField(max_length=300)
    question_slug=models.SlugField(editable=False)
    start_poll_at = models.DateTimeField(null=True)
    end_poll_at = models.DateTimeField(null=True)
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    audit_obj=generic.GenericRelation(Audit)
    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.question


class Choice(models.Model):
    ## TODO: Document
    choice = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    poll=models.ForeignKey(Poll)
    audit_obj=generic.GenericRelation(Audit)

class Vote(models.Model):
    ## TODO: Document
    choice=models.ForeignKey(Choice)
    Ip_Address=models.IPAddressField(editable=False)
    vote_at=models.DateTimeField("Vote at", editable=False)
```

here is the core/modes.py

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.contrib.contenttypes.models import ContentType
from django.contrib.contenttypes import generic


class Audit(models.Model):
    ## TODO: Document
    # Polymorphic model using generic relation through DJANGO content type
    created_at = models.DateTimeField("Created at", auto_now_add=True)
    created_by = models.ForeignKey(User, db_column="created_by", related_name="%(app_label)s_%(class)s_y+")
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField("Updated at", auto_now=True)
    updated_by = models.ForeignKey(User, db_column="updated_by", null=True, blank=True,
                                   related_name="%(app_label)s_%(class)s_y+")
    content_type = models.ForeignKey(ContentType)
    object_id = models.PositiveIntegerField(unique=True)
    content_object = generic.GenericForeignKey('content_type', 'object_id')
```

and here is polls/admin.py

```
from django.core.context_processors import request
from polls.models import Poll, Choice
from core.models import *
from django.contrib import admin

class ChoiceInline(admin.StackedInline):
    model = Choice
    extra = 3

class PollAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    inlines = [ChoiceInline]

admin.site.register(Poll, PollAdmin)
```

Am quite new to django, what am trying to do here, insert a record in audit when a record is inserted in polls and then update that same record when a record is updated in polls.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can override the `save()` method of `Poll` model or you can use [Django Signals](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/signals/)

to do it.

try something like:

```
def save(self, *args, **kwargs,request):    
     super(ModelName, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
     ## followed by your code
```

you can save your model instance using

```
modelinstance.save(request)
```

Comment: Am not quite how to override save() and get to pass the user session as well. If you can share a link with how to do such a thing or help me with guidelines, I would appreciate it. Btw, I just started using Python and Django couple weeks ago :)